# Plotting vast amount of data to a scrollable plot in vb2010

Tags: vb.net, graphics, picturebox, scrollable

I have a data (csv) file with 250,000 records of 9-bit binary data. I need to plot it in a way that allows a user to scroll through the plot. I have tried a picture box plus a scrollbar, with the scrollbar controlling the Top property of the PictureBox. What happens is that when plotted data is scrolled out of sight, it gets erased from the PictureBox.

Here's the ***VB2010*** code that plots one bit, showing all the graphics stuff I have.  I have omitted test code to manually generate data points.

```
Public Class Form1
Const myPixelHeight = 10
Const myPixelWidth = 10
Dim myGraphics As Graphics
Dim myPen As Pen
Dim TotalImageHeight As Integer
Dim Rec As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TotalImageHeight = PictureBox1.Height
    myGraphics = PictureBox1.CreateGraphics
    PictureBox1.Image = New Bitmap(500, 10000)
    myPen = New Pen(Brushes.DarkMagenta, myPixelHeight)
End Sub


Private Sub DrawOneBit(Record As Integer, Sensor As Integer)
    Dim HDistance As Integer, VDistance As Integer
    VDistance = Record * myPixelHeight
    HDistance = Sensor * myPixelWidth * 1.1
    myGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, HDistance, VDistance, HDistance + myPixelWidth, VDistance)
End Sub
```

This is my second attempt at asking this question. First time it was "put on hold" for being too vague? complicated? imprecise? I edited it but it has remained in the bit bucket.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to use your own graph builder? Why don't you use mschart to plot your points?

Comment: Thank you @xavier. One reason for not using MSChart is that I googled and googled, and found references to versions all the way back to ocx. days. No easy way of separating out those items relevant to VB2010.

Anyhow, I solved the problem another way. Instead of trying to scroll a huge PictureBox, I simply use a small p.b. and re-plot data from a huge array whenever a scroll bar value changes. The updates are a bit slow, but adequate.